# Accessing Windows & Ubuntu shared external drive

Tags: partitioning, windows

Tried 'gparted' and 'Disks' in Ubuntu but cannot access data.  I can see the drive however.  I have tried 'Computer Manager' in Windows but cannot access data.

I need access to the drive, please help.

Comment: Could you post output of fdisk -l /dev/xxx where /dev/xxx is your external hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

If your drive is formatted in EXT4 or EXT3, windows will **not** see it. Windows can **only** see NTFS or FATxx formatted drives. On the other hand, Ubuntu will see about everything.

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Use actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. Drivers for ext2fs and reiserfs on Windows _are exist_.

Comment: Ubuntu isn't accessing the data though it can see the drive and partitions.

Comment: If your Windows partition is in sleep mode, hibernate mode, Ubuntu will not open this partition for safety reasons. **shut down** windows properly, and disable 'fast startup' option.